# Using google web fonts in app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried using

```css
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Enriqueta|Cantarell' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

to include the above fonts Enriqueta and Cantarell in my app script but its not working.Is there any other way to use the above fonts in my app script?

Comment: Are you actually using those fonts? The link is valid, you just have to use `font-family: 'Cantarell'`

Comment: Yes i am using it but there is no effect.It works in raw html file but in google app script its not working.

Comment: I just used and in GAS and it works perfectly, share your published HTML if you need further assistance.

Comment: This is the link to the app script file-https://script.google.com/d/11Qe6vPRaSMTrcgHRHY_mhGeF5Kthglt1nweUpY0w3VhpWorALvCGhY7q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the output link https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx4_rxEhmJjxXcklvf7DyMQDPoVOv2Pu4k_qDugbgP2r6fdQHc/exec

Comment: Check the url of the font. In your code you have "http" instead of "https". let me know if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an outdated version of the HTMLService sandbox, you should add sandbox IFRAME after the `evaluate`, just as show everywhere in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Also, all URLs loaded must be served as secure (`https`), just as noted by Gerardo.